# Why can't I update more than one column at the same time using With keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have an update statement shown below that works fine, I used a with statement in the subquery to greatly improve performance but for some reason I'm not allowed to add an additional column from the same table to update.

Works:

```
UPDATE Table_A SET (Col_One) = (WITH OneValue AS (SELECT DISTINCT t.Col_One
                                                  FROM Table_Two t, Table_A a
                                                  WHERE t.id = a.New_Id))
                                SELECT Col_One FROM OneValue);
```

What I'd like to do is just include another column to update also from table_two like this

```
UPDATE Table_A SET (Col_One, Col_Two) = (WITH OneValue AS (SELECT DISTINCT t.Col_One, T.Col_two
                                                  FROM Table_Two t, Table_A a
                                                  WHERE t.id = a.New_Id))
                                SELECT Col_One, Col_Two FROM OneValue);
```

but I get ora-01767 update set expression must be a subquery. I understand this error but fail to see how I'm generating it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any reason why performance would benefit from the subquery factoring clause. Check the execution plans to see if there's a difference.

Comment: Well being new to coding, I'm not sure I can correctly answer you except to say that I was having trouble with performance from table 2 which is a very large table. I looked around and found some very helpful update optimzation info through askTom [link]( http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:288016031632) , applied it to my situation and performance went from > 5 minutes to < 10 seconds.

Comment: +1 for looking at asktom, but -1 for not following the philosophy exposed there :) Have a look for how he does performance comparisons. Use DBMS_Xplan to get execution plans for the queries and look for differences, and beware of a second query benefiting from data caching

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to work (it did with a simple query using DUAL anyway):

```
UPDATE Table_A SET (Col_One, Col_Two) = (select col_one, col_two from
                                          (WITH OneValue AS (SELECT DISTINCT t.Col_One, T.Col_two
                                                  FROM Table_Two t, Table_A a
                                                  WHERE t.id = a.New_Id))
                                           SELECT Col_One, Col_Two FROM OneValue)
                                        );
```

As for why it doesn't work if the subquery starts with "WITH", I can only imagine that it is because the designers of Oracle SQL hadn't anticipated this usage.

Comment: This workaround works. Thanks for answering so quickly. It does strike me as being unnecessarily redundant though but being new to this I can't help but wonder if it has some logical reason for it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  I was stumped by this same issue and starting to get pretty frustrated.  Still not sure why it works, but at least it does! :)