# Unable to update multiple columns with 'with' clause

Tags: oracle

I am using following query (which is working fine for one column ie base_price) but when i am trying to update more than one column I am getting ORA-01767: UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery.

```
UPDATE quote_item qi
SET (qi.base_price,qi.base_cost)
  =
  ( WITH baseVersion AS
  (SELECT qi1.quote_oid, qi1.item_num, qi1.sub_item_num as sub_item_num,  q1.quote_num,  qi1.base_price,  qi1.base_cost
  FROM quote q1,
    quote_item qi1
  WHERE q1.oid         = qi1.quote_oid
  AND q1.quote_type_oid=4
  AND q1.version_num = 0
  )
SELECT bv.base_price,bv.base_cost
FROM baseVersion bv,
  quote revQuote
WHERE revQuote.oid      = qi.quote_oid
AND revQuote.quote_num  = bv.quote_num
AND qi.item_num          =bv.item_num
AND qi.sub_item_num      =bv.sub_item_num
AND revQuote.version_num >0 and revQuote.quote_type_oid=4
  )
  where qi.quote_type_oid=4;
```

After some looking around I found a solution that it can be done by selecting again from the with clause but i am not able to implement it in my query [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917381/why-cant-i-update-more-than-one-column-at-the-same-time-using-with-keyword).

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update more than one column from the same sub query . You can either reuse the subquery for the other column (I wouldn't recommend this as the query will be executed twice) , or you can use oracle's `MERGE` . It will look something like this(adjust it) :

```
MERGE INTO quote_item qi
USING ( Your subquery goes here ) t
 ON(t.oid      = qi.quote_oid
    AND qi.item_num          =t.item_num
    AND qi.sub_item_num      =t.sub_item_num)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
     SET qi.col1 = ..,
         qi.col2 = ..
```